# Error when installing nix : the group 'nixbld' specified in 'build-users-group' does not exist

Tags: nix, ubuntu, error, install

I am trying to install nix/plutus following the below instructions :
https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/Ubuntu.html

The first step to install curl when fine. I get below error when installing nix :

sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --no-daemon

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  4046  100  4046    0     0   8376      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8376
downloading Nix 2.5.1 binary tarball for x86_64-linux from 'https://releases.nixos.org/nix/nix-2.5.1/nix-2.5.1-x86_64-linux.tar.xz' to '/tmp/nix-binary-tarball-unpack.4wSWtNaOSw'...
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 27.1M  100 27.1M    0     0  7549k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:-- 7549k
Note: a multi-user installation is possible. See https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/installation/installing-binary.html#multi-user-installation
warning: installing Nix as root is not supported by this script!
performing a single-user installation of Nix...
copying Nix to /nix/store...........................................
warning: the group 'nixbld' specified in 'build-users-group' does not exist
warning: the group 'nixbld' specified in 'build-users-group' does not exist
installing 'nix-2.5.1'
error: the group 'nixbld' specified in 'build-users-group' does not exist
/tmp/nix-binary-tarball-unpack.4wSWtNaOSw/unpack/nix-2.5.1-x86_64-linux/install: unable to install Nix into your default profile

How can I can get past this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't run the installer as root! Run it as a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

I used the command:
`sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install)`
(it seems to work)

I had to remove the:   `--no-daemon`  qualifier from the command I used previously

Answer (score 0):

I always install as root. I get error with all the scripts. Except this one (multi-user):

```
sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --daemon
```